# How can i create a Root User in Django?

Tags: django, user-defined-functions, root

I want to create a root user `RootUser` under which there will be all the companies and under each company there will be different users which i have already done using `CustomUser` model. That root user won't have any access to the data of other companies including  the users (which is defined in `CustomUser` model) of those companies under each company. The root user can only create companies. Now my question is how do I create the root user `RootUser` or? Do I need a separate app for this or do I have to create the root user in the `CustomUser` model or is there a better way to do this? Here is my `CustomUser` model. I would appreciate if anyone could at least help me with the approach. Thank you.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, "Super Admin"),
        (2, "Staff"),
        (3, "Users"),
    )
    user_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    nid_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    nid_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nid_images', blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)

    last_active = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    profile_picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='profile_pictures', blank=False)

    def is_online(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        # Assuming the user is online if they have been active in the last 5 minutes
        return now - self.last_active < timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_id:
            # find the last user
            last_user = CustomUser.objects.order_by('-user_id').first()

            if last_user:
                last_user_id = int(last_user.user_id)

                if str(last_user_id).startswith('445') and len(str(last_user_id)) >= 6:
                    # Ensure at least 6 digits
                    new_user_id_str = str(last_user_id + 1).zfill(6)
                    new_user_id = int(new_user_id_str)
                else:
                    new_user_id = 445002

            else:
                new_user_id = 445001

            self.user_id = new_user_id

        if not self.username or self.username == 'None':
            self.username = str(new_user_id)

        super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Since you are extending built-in user model, how about using `Group`? Create a "Root User" group and assign "Can create company" permission to the group. Then you can add any CustomUser to the group.

Comment: BTW, `AbstractUser` has two fields: `is_superuser` and `is_staff`, which makes `user_type` duplicated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I wanted to have the `RootUser` in such a way that it has only access to modify or add `Company`. If I use `custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)` in the `Company` model, I am creating a relation with all the users even though I can control who can access it. I wanted to keep the `RootUser` completely separate. I tried to do this using `Group` but is this the best approach since the `RootUser`is also one of the users of each of those `Company` even though he can't have any access to their data. Thank you again

Comment: I believe you can do fine-grain access control with built-in `User`, `Group` and `Permission`. I have no idea why you want complete separateness, so I cannot say using `Group` is the best approach. So far I can only suggest you give it a try and see if you encountered any vital problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created a permission group and then assigned those group of permissions to that user